# moto G MTP not connected on windows XP

Tags: mtp

My Moto G MTP is not working in windows xp for any files transfer from pc to device. I tested the same device on Windows 7 and ubuntu, and it worked like a charm . Does Windows XP needs any special drivers to detect the device MTP ?

Comment: Have you checked the Group User Policies for USB device detection and driver installation?

Comment: where can GROUP USER POLICIES for USB be found ?

Comment: Provided the details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The MTP driver was bundled with Windows Media Player 11 on Windows XP. To get Media Player 11, you must download it from the Microsoft site here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/download-windows-media-player

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the drivers need to be installed, why don't you try connecting your PC with the internet and then try connection you device. If it still doesn't works then I couldn't say much about it but I think the problem may lies because Microsoft has take down support with the XP. So, I think that may be the reason behind !

Comment: Peter, tried to check the drivers with option (check from internet) but it did nt work

Comment: Well, can't comment over it exactly but I think i have ran out of option. I think the problem may be encounter because of the support I guess. As you have said that its working over other OS i.e. Win7 or Win8 then I guess support may be the reason. :( wait a bit more while to see if some other user can came up with something more on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

1. Go to `Run` and type `gpedit.msc` and hit `OK`.
2. Go to `Administrative template` under `Computer Configuration`. Then `Custom Policy setting` and select `Click on Restrict Drives`.
3. Double-click on Disable USB Removable Drives .
4. Select Disable for Allow to USB Removable drives and click `OK`.

Now go to `Run` again and type `regdit` and hit `OK`.

1. Navigate to the following registry path: 
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor`
2. Click on USBStor , then Click on Start in the Right Panel.
3. Type `3` in Value data Box , and click on `Hexadecimal` , then click ok